# Cxf HTTPS client example

Tags: java, https, client, cxf

I need a Cxf client which can deal with HTTPS wsdl url.
The cxf documentation isn't really big, so i would appreciate some help.

Is there any example of what i want ? google isn't my friend today :(

Thx for helping me.

---

EDIT1:
I just don't know how to do this.
When i try :

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean(); factory.setAddress("https://mysite/view/ext-services/dpDataService?wsdl");
factory.setServiceClass(DPDataService.class);
DPDataService client = (DPDataService) factory.create();
client.getAllHostServiceMetric("1", "1");
```

I have the error :

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Could not find conduit initiator for transport
```

---

EDIt2:

with :

`factory.setWsdlURL`

i have the error :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

---

EDIt3:

I create a keystore and add the certificate, then i set the property:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "myKeyStore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
```

But now the error is Exception in thread "main" `org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not find definition for service {http://unknown.namespace/}`

i see that the console say : reating Service {http://unknown.namespace/}

maybe i forgot something.

---

EDIT4 : Many news :

It seems that the https is no longer a problem.
but i still need help :)

So here with this code :

```
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory factory = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
        Client client = factory.createClient("https://url/services?wsdl");
Object[] res = client.invoke("getSomething", "param");
```

I have the error :

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Both jaxb:version and version are present
```

Another code :

```
ClientProxyFactoryBean
```

=> some error

with : `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean + setWsdlURL`

```
Could not find definition for service {http://unknown.namespace/}DPDataServiceService.
```

Comment: Using HTTP with SSL (HTTPS) with CXF should work the same way as using HTTP. Is there something in particular that is not working for you?

Comment: With more experience, it seems to be the ws-security, but i don't resolve it.Sopaui works so... :(